# Unpack index, key, and value when enumerating over dictionary items

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have the following code:

```
my_dict = {str(n*100): n for n in range(5)}
for index, key_value in enumerate(my_dict.items()):
    print(index, key_value[0], key_value[1])
```

Which would create a dictionary with 5 keys and then print (index, key, value) for each key-value pair in the dictionary.

Is there a more elegant way to unpack the dictionary items so that I could do something like:

```
for index, key, value in unpack_index_and_items(my_dict):
    print(index, key, value)
```

Preferably I'm looking for a one-line replacement for the unpack_index_and_items placeholder and not an actual function.

Comment: `for index, (key, value) in enumerate(things.items()):`? But the index of a key-value pair has no meaning, as dictionaries aren't ordered.

Comment: Of course it's that simple. Thanks.

Bonus points if someone can explain why that second tuple isn't automatically unpacked?

Comment: Well why *would* it be? Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Yep that makes sense now that I think about it more. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just use this:

```
for index, (k, val) in enumerate(my_dict.items()):
    print(index, k, val)
```

Note the parenthesis around `k, val`. Without it you get `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`. The reason is `items()` returns a `(key, value)` pair. Look [here](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items). Without parenthesis, the tuple returned by `items()` gets assigned to `k`, and there is nothing to assign to `val`, which is why you get the error `need more than 2 values to unpack`. However, with the parenthesis, the tuple returned by `items()` is assigned to the tuple `(k, val)`.

I renamed the variables to `k` and `val` to distinguish between `(key, value)` pair returned by `items()` and the variable names in this example.

---

Edit: Read about tuple assignment [here](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html#tuple-assignment). Also [PEP 3132: Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Comment: Appreciate the extra detail, if you can add a link to documentation for the tuple assignment syntax I'll accept this as the answer.

That's not something I had seen enough to know that I could even do it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this:

```
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(my_dict.items()):
    print index, key, value
```